# Instrumentation Testing Room migrations

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room, database-migration

We have a project that extensively uses offline storage hence Room. The database has been migrated so many times that It is currently on V77.

we are planning to incorporate migration testing now ( I know it is too late ) hence want to write test for migration fron v77 to v78.

I wanted to know what is the best way to write tests for this scenario , The database is huge and complex containing joins etc.
I tried following the articles on Room migration tests but it is only for a small schema.

Also the Room generated schema jsons have been limited , would that be an issue for this ? and is there a way to generate the previous versions like 1.json etc.

[image]

I have followed the online medium articles precisely like it has been implemented and has been getting errors when migration happens on database joins etc.

Then I tried to follow the Android Doc for testing migrations but since I dont have the json files for pervious versions , I cannot implement that.

Can anyone suggest a good repo or already implemented tests for a similiar use case
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

> and is there a way to generate the previous versions like 1.json etc.

yes, you can change the code for the previous version(s) so that in the @Database annotation `exportSchema = true` is coded AND that the room.schemaLocation is set accordingly (and obviously that the version number is set accordingly). You can the compile the project and the schema for that version will be generated.

- Obviously due to the above changes the version being compiled is not exactly the same. However, the schema should be exactly as required as long as no other changes have been made that affect the schema.